# How to draw a line with button the center of the line

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a `<hr>` line in CSS. And there is a button at the center of the line which cuts that line in the middle. So how can I achieve this effect in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `margin-bottom` in minus to your `button`. Write like this:

```
button{
 margin-bottom:-20px;
 position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.button-holder{display:block; height:30px; border-bottom:1px solid #ff0000; position:relative; text-align:center;}
input{position:absolute; bottom:-13px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="button-holder">
    <input type="button" value="button in the middle of HR" />
</div>
```